# Update column with inner select via replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to go throu a table and remove a line out of the value.  What I wanted to do was something like this:

```
UPDATE infotabs
SET [content] = 
    replace(
     replace(
        (
            SELECT [content] 
            FROM   infotabs AS ib
            WHERE  ib.infotab_id = i.infotab_id  
        ), '<p>', '')
    , '</p>', '')
WHERE infotab_id= 
    (
        SELECT i.infotab_id 
        FROM         infotabs AS i
        WHERE     ([content] LIKE '%<p>%') 
    )
```

But this fails with:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>  The multi-part identifier
>   "i.infotab_id" could not be bound.

So basically I need to loop thru the table and rmove all <p> and </p> from the columns.  can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you stop thinking about this as a loop, and think about it as a set, you'll find this query is a lot more logical than what you're trying:

```
UPDATE infotabs SET content = REPLACE(REPLACE(content, '<p>', ''), '</p>', '')
 WHERE content LIKE '%<p>%' OR content LIKE '%</p>%';
```

As I mentioned in my comment to Gordon's answer, which wasn't well received, I had added an additional where clause here so that all rows are updated, regardless of whether they contain only `<p>`, only `</p>`, or both. Sorry I didn't disclose why initially.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
UPDATE infotabs
    SET [content] =  replace(replace([content], '<p>', ''), '</p>', '')
    WHERE [content] LIKE '%<p>%'
```

It seems much simpler.

Comment: While probably unlikely, this will miss rows where only `</p>` is found in `content`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . although I admire the criticism, this is the logic in the original query.  Yes, searching for both probably does make logical sense.  The important point is removing the subqueries.

Comment: It is not criticism, and it is not directed at you. Please don't be so defensive. I'm merely pointing out a potential flaw in the logic, regardless of who introduced it. Since future readers are more likely to look at the code in an answer vs. in the question, I thought it was an important point to bring up. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  . . . Your point is entirely appropriate.  The comment should then go on the original question.

Comment: Why? I've addressed it here and in my answer. Future readers are much more likely to pay attention to answers and comments on answers than comments on the original question.

Comment: I will aimit yes much easier with out the subquesrys, just thought it lost scoop once pulled.  So .. I can't seem toe tell who got here first.  Both are right and would be right so.. if someone can say which on was first then I'll mark it off.  Thank you both.  Cheers --

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I believe my answer was here first.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you were replying to my comment, not the op's. Anyway there is no reason to rely on "I think"... you can order answers by oldest and you can also mouse over "5 hours ago" and the actual timestamp is shown.

Comment: ha yes didn't know there was the real time in there.  Off by a min.  Thanks you two for the help.